# Is it possible to turn off keyword substitution for 'svn export'?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, cvs

I would like to use `svn export` to export a bunch of files out of a Subversion repository.  And I also wish to forgo keyword expansion on any of the keywords found in these files regardless of the `svn:keywords` property on this file.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm doing this because I want to compare the files in the repository against a set of those same files that are not in the repository and have unexpanded keywords.  A long long time ago I had a repository in CVS.  A long time ago I did a flag day conversion to Subversion.  Now I'm trying to convert the whole history to Mercurial and I want to identify exactly which version in Subversion corresponds most closely to the last version in CVS using diff without having to wade through expanded keyword differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been implemented in SVN 1.7 (released 2011-10-11) as a `--ignore-keywords` option 
to `svn export`:

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-09/0187.shtml

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not. You'll have to [set up your diff tool to ignore those differences](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/users@subversion.tigris.org/8099209.html).

Comment: Since I control the repository I can also just do a property delete on them all then remove that revision from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git to accomplish this.

```
git svn clone http://example.com/path/to/svn/repo
```

Once that command is complete, the only thing you have extra that you wouldn't have with svn export is a .git directory in the top level directory.  Remove that directory and you'll have an equivalent to svn export with keywords off.