# How to keep revision timestamps while converting a repository from Mercurial to Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

Because of work policies, I'm forced to use Subversion. Currently I've developed some code using Mercurial, and I have to convert this repository to a new Subversion repository. The current Mercurial repository also contains legacy code parts that I copied from another SVN repository (a HW driver), and this code contains keywords (like `$Id: ...$`) that were expanded while I copied the code.

My current approach to do the conversion is:

```
hg convert --dest-type svn repository.hg repository.svn
```

This works, unfortunately it does not preserve the timestamps of Mercurial revisions. Additionally, it expands tags in some legacy code parts where someone wrote `$Id: ...$` stuff.

The questions:

1. How can I export to Subversion, keeping the timestamps of revisions.
2. How can I convert without expanding $Id:$ style keywords, or, even better, delete the offending lines while converting. Is this possible, or do I have to modify the history of the Mercurial dump before converting to make sure no keywords are present?

Sorry if this question has been answered already, I've searched intensely with Google and on here, but I cannot find an answer for this problem. Especially the timestamp problem must be something that others have already run into.

Cheers,
H.

**EDIT:** I've since created a script that extracts timestamps from a Mercurial export file and updates a Subversion dumpfile, which is nothing more but a kludge, but it works. The `$Id:` problem is still unsolved, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

It is a tricky issue. Why aproaching the solution differently:

https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home

This is an extension to Mercurial which allows you to access it as a SVN Client, could it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the policy is to only have SVN repositories, while hgsubversion allows you to use SVN repositories with Mercurial semantics. But my problem is while converting a Mercurial repository to SVN. Afterwards, hgsubversion might be the tool that I use. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I want to re-suggest [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) as a solution. In the normal case, it is used to access a Subversion repository using `hg`, but you can use it to convert a Mercurial repository to Subversion as well if you are not afraid to work on your history of changesets. (If you know how to work with changesets, you have quite a bit of control over the process.)

Essentially, you have to do the following steps:

1. Make your Mercurial history linear (this is required for Subversion); you can use the [Collapse extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) to collapse any non-linear area of the history into a single changeset
2. Create a Subversion repository or directory and `hg pull` this SVN path (using hgsubversion) into your Mercurial repository. The Subversion path may have to be non-empty for this, but as long as there is no overlap with the files in the Mercurial repository, this should be fine.
3. Rebase all of the changesets from the Mercurial history on top of the head of the Subversion history. This is done using the [Rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension). If there is no overlap, this should be an automatic operation.
4. Use `hg push` to send the result back to Subversion. The linear set of changes that descend from the former head of the Subversion repository will be added to the Subversion path.

Check [this blog article](http://blog.kalleberg.org/post/2337246985/merging-a-mercurial-repository-back-into-subversion) for some concrete command-line commands that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it again -- does it preserve timestamps of revisions?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't. In my test, the Subversion commits have a timestamp that corresponds to the point when they were pushed to the SVN repo.

Comment: Too bad :( I wonder why timestamps are not adjusted accordingly, it's important to see when changes were made.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the **keyword substitution** once on SVN and I had to add a `svn:keywords` property to the working folder indicating which keyword(s) to be substituted. So, deleting this property should do the job.

[This article on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215651/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-keyword-substitution-for-svn-export) is possibly related to this question.

Comment: Yes, but I want to convert to Subversion ... or do you mean converting to SVN and converting back to remove those lines?

Comment: I meant just to switch off the keyword expansion, wherever it comes from, because I understand it as a feature that is just working when files are "checked out" (i.e. not when stored in the repository). If this is right, you have to switch off the keyword expansion in Mercurial, because perhaps `hg convert` does an `hg update` before a `svn commit`. But at all it's just a guess.

Comment: I just checked it: If you had keyword expansion activated in a Hg repository and files already committed with `$Revision$` for example, then clone the repo and look at the file in your working folder again. The changeset's hash value is gone. After this you may deal with the above string using some combination of grep/sed or any other tool that may handle multiple files with a find and replace algorithm.

Comment: If you activate and configure the keyword extension again in the cloned repo, the hash value is present again after updating the working folder (`hg update null; hg update`). So it's proven that expansion of the keywords is done when updating.

Comment: Ah, I see that I have mis-formulated the keyword stuff -- the thing is the Mercurial repo contains some legacy code (a driver) that was copied from a SVN repo which has keyword style expansion, and the keywords were expanded. Now I have those lines in my Mercurial repo (without using keywords). This gives ugliness if I convert back to SVN ... :> Actually what I really need is to filter my hg repository and remove those lines entirely from the history (yes that's dirty -- but I'm the only user right now). Then I can just convert all to SVN ... which leaves me with bad timestamps still :(

Comment: I can see clearly now :-) So it's about "changing the history in Hg". I'll add another idea as a new answer because this one has got some credits.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem now: You have a Hg repository which was once converted from SVN, where keyword expansion had been used. Now the expanded keywords remain unchanged in the Hg repo. You now want to strip those keywords (or just their expanded values) from the Hg history, preserving author, date/time, commit message and of course changed files.

This is just an idea, I have never done this in practical, but ... Speaking just of mercurial, I think it's possible to do this by a combination of usual mercurial behaviour, just for one branch and without tags and other branches:

1. Clone the intended source repository
2. Prepare an empty Hg repository
3. Perform `hg log > logfile.txt` over the source repo on that branch you want to change
4. Parse the file getting a structured list of all necessary information like changeset number, user, date and summary, store this into a data structure that allows easy iteration
5. Iterate through the list (or directly use the log file) and ...

   - delete all working files from the destination repo
   - export a changeset from the source repo to the working copy of the destination repo
   - change anything in the working files you want to do
   - `hg addremove`
   - `hg commit -m ... -d ... -u ...`
6. Repeat step 5 as often as necessary

The drawback is that the changesets will get new hash values, so tags and bookmarks need to be updated.

If there are other branches that have to be migrated:

1. Update the destination repo to that branch's starting point
2. and the source repo, too
3. insert steps 3 to 6 from the above list here

Perhaps there is some more work to be done, but I think this could work. As told before, I've never done this.

Comment: Yes exactly, parts of the repository were copied from a `SVN` repo. I've done a lot with the `mq` and `transplant` extension in Mercurial before, but I see no way to filter out those lines. My current approach is to substitute all `$` in `$[A-Z]` patterns by an underscore, so line count and other things are left intact. But this is no real solution. The only plus is that it works with my timestamp correction script; 2 kludges in one program ... ;(

Comment: Do you happen to have an idea regarding the preserving of revision timestamps? Maybe there's a better way than my script.

Comment: From Hg to Hg, the above process would preserve the timestamp of any changeset, because you read it from the source and set it with the commit (-d parameter). In this case the given timestamp is used instead of the current time. But during the checkin into SVN I did not find any similar parameter.

Comment: Your posting has put me on a new track regarding the diff. I think actually what I need is some way to modify either the patches or rebuild history with the `addremove` subcommand. This is all really dirty, but the requirement is dirty so that was expected anyways ;-) I can imagine a Mercurial extension to `hg convert`, for example a command line option `--exclude-lines=<pattern>` that filters out lines from files.

Comment: I don't think this command line option is a good idea, because this particular operation doesn't belong to mercurial. Some kind of "piping" could do a better job, as it would be an open and standard interface. BTW, thanks for the credits, glad I could help :-)